# Magento product page is not displaying in Chrome

Tags: magento, google-chrome

On the website I'm working on http://www.idealtilenyc.com/index.php/lena-test-tile.html

For some reason product page is not displaying in Chrome, in Firefox and IE everything seams fine. Does anybody knows what might be wrong?

Thank You!

Here is the code:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">



    <!------------------ SHOWROOM -------------->



    <?php

    $current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ($current_category->getName() == 'Showroom'): ?>  //this is line 55 

    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like your server page memory limit is low. So try to increase your page memory limit in php.ini file. Set memory limit like, memory_limit = 250M

Comment: Thank you! I changed php.ini, but now there appears another error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /home1/idealtil/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 55

but in Firefox it's working fine

Comment: Isn't working fine in FireFox here. And it's a server issue, not a browser issue if it throws an error. That's a PHP interpreter stack trace.

Comment: _Fatal error: Call to a member function **getName()** on a **non-object** in /home1/idealtil/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/catalog/p‌​roduct/view.phtml on line 55_ <-- This template is calling **getName()** improperly and not passing a product object to it so it can find the product name. This needs to be opened as a new question with some php code so we can even begin to answer.

Comment: It seems like you tried to modify your view.phtml file. Please post your code here (view.phtml). or replace that view.phtml file  with another (original)view.phtml file that is located in base directory with the same path. Before that backup yr old view.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not altered so much on view.phtml, then top 2nd line code will be `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`

Now, use above object to print name of the product like: `<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>`

Hope this will help!